# Compound Tests with GoogleTest?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

If I have something like:

```
ASSERT_TRUE(RANGE(val1, val2, abs_err) || RANGE(val1, val3, abs_err));
```

How would I use `ASSERT_NEAR` instead of `ASSERT_TRUE`?

I've attempted to break up the statement into two `ASSERT_NEAR` statements, like below, but the test fails.

```
ASSERT_NEAR(val1, val2, abs_err);
ASSERT_NEAR(val1, val3, abs_err);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is: any of these two condition should be true.
So use [`::testing::AnyOf(m1,m2,...)`](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#composite-matchers)!

Equivalent of `ASSERT_NEAR(lhs,rhs,max_error)` in matchers world is [`::testing::DoubleNear(rhs,max_error)`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CheatSheet.md#floating-point-matchers) - so your example will look like this:

```
ASSERT_THAT(val1, AnyOf(DoubleNear(val2, abs_err),
                        DoubleNear(val3, abs_err)));
```

---

If you need both of your conditions are true - use `::testing::AllOf` - actually your attempt is just equivalent of `AllOf` - that is why it failed.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think to investigate the GoogleMock things.